# Standard checking if user has active subscription(auto renewable subscription). IOS Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, in-app-purchase

I did a lot of reading about auto renewable subscription but I have problem on how to check if a user has active subscription.

this is how I get the receipt

```
func validateRecipt(callback:(receipt:NSDictionary?)->()){
        let recuptUrl = NSBundle.mainBundle().appStoreReceiptURL
        if let receipt: NSData = NSData(contentsOfURL:recuptUrl!) {

            //https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt    //TEST ENVIRONMENT
            //https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt        //PRODUCTION ENVIRONMENT
            let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt")!, cachePolicy: NSURLRequestCachePolicy.UseProtocolCachePolicy, timeoutInterval: 10)

            let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
            request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
            let receiptdata:NSString = receipt.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 0))
            let payload:NSDictionary = {["receipt-data" : receiptdata, "password" : "mySharedKey"]}()
           //, password\" : \"" + EGConstants.sharedSecret + "\" }"

            do {

            let payloadData:NSData = try(NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(payload, options: NSJSONWritingOptions(rawValue: 0)))

            request.HTTPBody = payloadData
            let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) { (data, response, err) in

                do {
                    let json = try(NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableLeaves) as? NSDictionary)

                    if(err != nil) {
                        print(err!.localizedDescription)
                        let jsonStr = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                        print("Error could not parse JSON: '\(jsonStr)'")
                        callback(receipt: nil)
                    }
                    else {
                        if let parseJSON = json {


                            callback(receipt: parseJSON)
                        }
                        else {
                            let jsonStr = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                            print("Recipt Error: \(jsonStr)")
                            callback(receipt: nil)
                        }
                    }
                } catch {

                }
            }



            task.resume()

            } catch {}
        }
    }
```

my questions are: 
1. How to check if user has active subscription using Receipt? (do i need to parse the receipt and get the last `expires_date` of last transaction of `product subscription`?)

2. Is it fine to refresh receipt every time I launch the app?(so that I could check if user cancelled his subscription) if not when do I need to do the refresh receipt?

ps. If I have wrong concept or questions please guide me to right path. Thanks in advance

Comment: Although, this does not answer your question, I'd like to mention that you must not do the local receipt validation by sending the request to the itunes. This validation should be performed by the server as the only one side under your control. See [Validating Receipts With the App Store](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateRemotely.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010573-CH104-SW1)

Comment: @EugeneDubinin server means outside my app? like webserver?

Comment: Yes. The server which you could submit `Base64` receipt data to and receive the validation result being done by the server with iTunes from.

Comment: @EugeneDubinin is it possible not making any other thing like server stuff?

Comment: In order to find out the local validation procedure read [Validating Receipts Locally](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateLocally.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010573-CH1-SW2), **BUT** again, I am not sure that validation is needed to solve your issue. I have no experience with subscriptions.

Comment: @EugeneDubinin but can't read the validation from local -- its new to me thats why i settle for validating from app store. thank you for your time Eugene

Comment: @CaffeineShots if it's still a problem for you, I posted an answer. You can explore the library or just use it.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, it's too late for the answer, but, lastly, I've been working on a similar problem. However, I had to parse and validate the receipt locally, which is better in my opinion, because you don't need to make an extra http call.

I have implemented a small library to simplify to work with In-App Receipt locally.

Feel free to use. [Github link](https://github.com/tikhop/TPInAppReceipt)

Here is an example of solving your problem:

```
import TPInAppReceipt

do {
    let receipt = try InAppReceiptManager.shared.receipt()

    //retrive active auto renewable subscription for a specific product and date
    let purchase = receipt.activeAutoRenewableSubscriptionPurchases(ofProductIdentifier: "ProductName", forDate: Date())

    //retrive all auto renewable subscription purchases for a specific product
    let allAutoRenewableSubscriptionPurchases = receipt.purchases(ofProductIdentifier: "productName").filter({ return $0.isRenewableSubscription })
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: I tried this code but nothing happens, just 2 warnings that it was never used

Comment: @BroSimple the library has been updated and there is an example on GitHub page

Comment: I dont see the example, I'm printing my json receipt the auto-renew but I can't figure out to validate this json with TPInAppReceipt

Comment: @BroSimple unfortunately you can't validate json file, you can only validate the local receipt

Comment: I got the receipt from my server which got it from Apple, what do I do from there? The Github has no clear instructions, I added the code in `Working With a Receipt` and inside that I added `Useful methods` and nothing happens, the only example project I see is the project itself which isn't functional

Comment: @BroSimple https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateRemotely.html

Comment: @BroSimple if you want to validate it locally, you no need to download the receipt and you can use the code provided on github page

Comment: I'm using Swift to its hard to use Apples docs, so even if I already got the receipt from my server from Apples server, I fetch the receipt again straight from Apple again and compare them? I would validate it locally only but I want it to be secure. very new to this

Comment: @BroSimple as i told you can't validate it using that lib if you are downloading the receipt from the server.

Comment: I thought the lib was for remote for some reason, so what do you recommend? I'm having so much trouble with validating

Comment: @BroSimple if u want to use the library you have to follow the code I provided also you can find wiki on cocoapod page where you can find all available public methods for validating the receipt

Comment: @BroSimple I'd recommend either validate it remotely using your own server or just follow the code I provided on github page

Comment: How would I validate it remotely? In the php script? I get the json receipt from server just fine but the validating fact is what I don't know, for auto-renewable. Any help? I even posted a question up few hours ago but no help.

Comment: @BroSimple I have no idea how to validate it using your own server, but I'm pretty sure you can google it easily

Comment: I've tried googling it but found nothing that can help me since I'm using Swift, I'm looking into SwiftStoreKit to see if I can validate the receipt

Comment: @BroSimple swift and server validation have nothing in common. You can use objc and the same validation server.

Comment: I will try my best but its very complicated, thank you

Comment: @BroSimple you are welcome, I hope i've helped you in some way. Good luck.

Comment: Sorry nvm that! I got inside the receipt now, just a quick question. What do i have to check in the receipt for auto renewable, in `latest_receipt_info` I check the `expires_date` and thats it?